# NodeJS unit testing with Mocha and Supertest - `assert` does not seem working as expected?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, assert, supertest

`assert` does not seem working as expected.

This is my package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "backpack-core": "^0.4.1",
    "mocha": "^3.5.0",
    "supertest": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_PATH=./server:./server/modules mocha ./test/*.js --compilers js:babel-core/register --recursive",
    "dev": "backpack dev",
    "build": "nuxt build && backpack build",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node build/main.js"
  },
```

My test:

```
'use strict'

import app from '../server/index'
import supertest from 'supertest'
import assert from 'assert'

const request = supertest.agent(app)

var _id
var name
describe('POST /api/users with data', function () {
  it('status code should be 200', function (done) {
    request
      .post('/api/users')
      .type('form')
      .send({name: 'tom'})
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res) {
        console.log(res.body)
        if (err) return done(err)

        name = res.body.ops[0].name.toString()
        _id = res.body.ops[0]._id.toString()
        console.log(name)

        assert(name, 'tomx') // should not pass this.

        done()
      })
  })
})
```

Result:

```
  POST /api/users with data
{ result: { ok: 1, n: 1 },
  ops: [ { id: 'xxx', name: 'tom', _id: '59a7c33ba17bd32431c4134b' } ],
  insertedCount: 1,
  insertedIds: [ '59a7c33ba17bd32431c4134b' ] }
tom
    ✓ status code should be 200 (54ms)
```

At `assert(name, 'tomx')` - Why is passed? It is `tom` that should be passed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assert` is just a shorthand for `assert.ok` which validates that the first argument is truthy https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_value_message

You should use `assert.equal` or `assert.strictEqual` instead. Another option is modifying your assertion:

`assert(name === 'tomx')`